# Could not resolve: org.springframework:spring-webmvc:5.3.20 in gradle projects

Tags: spring, performance, build.gradle, upgrade, compatibility

We are doing spring upgrade from Spring 5.2.16 to 5.3.20. While building the project. We are getting error

> Could not resolve: org.springframework:spring-webmvc:5.3.20

Answer (score 2):

It is the JDK compatibility related issue. If you are using following configuration in gradle.build file
sourceCompatibility = 1.7 and
targetCompatibility = 1.7

Change it to 1.8 and run "gradle eclipse" command. Problem will be solved !!

Thank you